# Recover password from Opera EMail client

Tags: ubuntu, email, passwords, opera, password-recovery

I'm using Opera 12 build in EMail client.
Cause Opera is not anymore so great with new websites I'd like to move on and change browser  and EMail client. But I can't do this cause I forgot password to one of my Email Accounts.

Is there any tool to recover OperaMail password? If not mby you can tell me where mail passwords are stored and what kind of encryption are they using (is this same method as in wand.dat file - DES with keys stored before encrypted data?).

Comment: If you don't use encrypted mail communication (unencryptd is still the default), the quickest way would be a tool like this: [Windows Password Sniffer](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/password_sniffer.html). 
Most likely there such tools exists also for linux.

Comment: Unfortunately all connections goes through TSL. Maybe when i change server options it will blindly send credentials. Anyway thanks for hint.